# Битрикс проблема с urlrewrite.php

Tags: битрикс

В urlrewrite.php добавлено правило для страницы /contract

```
<?php
$arUrlRewrite=array (
 
  0 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^\\/?\\/mobileapp/jn\\/(.*)\\/.*#',
    'RULE' => 'componentName=$1', 
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/mobileapp/jn.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ), 
  1 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/rest/#',
    'RULE' => '', 
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/rest/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/contract/([a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_]+)/?.*#',
    'RULE' => 'SECTION_CODE=$1',
    'PATH' => '/contract/detail.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),   
);
```

в файл detail.php добавлен компонент bitrix:news.detail

При переходе на страницу /contract/testing/ всё открывается, но если открыть параметры компонента и нажать кнопку сохранить, то эта страница становится 404 и если открыть файл urlrewrite.php, то этого правила уже нет

Подскажите как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

В правиле необходимо указать параметр ID. Этот параметр указывает, какой компонент или модуль ответственен за это правило. Можно указать 'ID' => NULL или 'ID' => 'myModule'.